# Django REST randomized query pagination

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In Django REST generic list view, I've overridden `get_query_set` method and set `paginate_by` to 25.

I want to randomize set of items in each page. However, when I randomized items in get_query_set method, whole set is randomized.

To clearify: Item list is `A B C D E F G` and let assume paginate_by is `2`
For first page it should return `A B` in random, for page 2 it should return `C D` in random etc.

Is there any tricky way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but it seems like you would need override the **paginate_queryset** method in your view to randomize the objects in the page. So it would be something like..

```
 # or use whatever you were using to randomize the list
 from random import shuffle

 class MyView(ListAPIView):

   def paginate_queryset(self, queryset):

      page = super(MyView, self).paginate_queryset(queryset):
      shuffle(page.object_list)
      return page
```

See the source code for ListAPIView for more information on how paginate_queryset works: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py

Comment: not sure if this is a valid response as for today, but I changed *shufle(page.object_list)* for *shuffle(page)*. I'm using DRF 2.2

Comment: Using `shuffle(page)` in 2022.